# postfix server on VM - mail relay

Tags: postfix, spam, libvirt, rspamd

I've setup a mail server according to this setup: https://thomas-leister.de/en/mailserver-debian-stretch/
The documentation itself looks quite good to me - is well explained and seems to work... almost.

## setup

The server itself is a VM that runs on a that uses KVM/libvirt virtualization and port forwarding for the ports 25/993 using iptables rules.

### virtual

- IP: 10.0.42.170 (NAT network)
- Debian 9
- Postfix 3.1.12
- Dovecot 2.2.27
- rspamd 2.1

### host

- IP: (public IP)
- Debian 9
- libvirt

My mailserver can receive mails, but when I try to send a mail as one of the mail users (using Thunderbird), I experience this problem:

1. Send mail to another **self-hosted** account: Mail gets marked as Spam
2. Send mail to an **external** mail account: Mail gets rejected with
   `5.7.1 <externalemail@domain.tld>: Relay access denied.`

I've set all of the DNS records for SPF, dmarc, ... as pointed out in the documentation, but still `rspamd` marks my mails either as spam, or doesn't allow sending them to external mail accounts.

here are some relevant mail headers. The actual domain / address / ip values have been changed, though: mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD, CLIENT_IP, user@MAILDOMAIN.TLD

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1;
    mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD;
    dkim=none;
    spf=neutral (mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD: CLIENT_IP is neither permitted nor denied by domain of user@MAILDOMAIN.TLD) smtp.mailfrom=user@MAILDOMAIN.TLD
X-Spamd-Bar: ++++++
X-Spam-Level: ******
Authentication-Results: mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD;
    dkim=none;
    dmarc=fail reason="No valid SPF, No valid DKIM" header.from=MAILDOMAIN.TLD (policy=reject);
    spf=neutral (mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD: CLIENT_IP is neither permitted nor denied by domain of user@MAILDOMAIN.TLD) smtp.mailfrom=user@MAILDOMAIN.TLD
X-Spam: Yes
```

When searching for alike problems here on serverfault and on superuser.com, I found some posts that indicate that `permit_sasl_authenticated` has to be set accordingly (see https://superuser.com/questions/1395511/im-stuck-with-postfix-on-debian-554-5-7-1-relay-access-denied) , but in my case this seems to be achieved via the `mua_client_restrictions` and `mua_relay_restrictions`

## DNS

### main domain:

**SPF**:
`MYDOMAIN.TLD.        3600    IN    TXT    "v=spf1 a:mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD ?all"`

**dmarc**:
`_dmarc.MYDOMAIN.TLD.    3600    IN    TXT    "v=DMARC1\; p=reject\;"`

**domainkey**:
`2019._domainkey.MYDOMAIN.TLD. 1417 IN    TXT    "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyBjU5POfOMC0DdzxAeImIKYCWR3frj9jXD3IB7XWIYwV9CK3LP2s+gNxqffneygVPD+tvBZgHbG+kn7tQP1EtHpG0bg/KYrF09r5/f7/ilZflF9RE+t5GQkwAZCtgeZ1FWX8CEYq2kqHpGWhyhBd1l9idaqh97jk6NiuXOzrCZ9dIjoLQ2G8kAMdH7ade0/CT" "dEL4GX4Jzd8Jbb/eFXzM/2kCJ8v7lFUz5zLeMfdYvAto1U6yZ3cEYVjwpFQQZYJ77zq/eS8F/JAvJJWe5OzPnJe4V+i8hFVmsAYHpNysxUFW9KmR/LOYw8ouqpXoMMfOt3ilBLtZZO4n9Dms4iDNQIDAQAB"`

### mail domain:

**SPF**:
`MAILDOMAIN.TLD.        3600    IN    TXT    "v=spf1 include:MYDOMAIN.TLD ?all"`

**dmarc**:
`_dmarc.MAILDOMAIN.TLD.    3600    IN    TXT    "v=DMARC1\; p=reject\;"`

**domainkey**:
`2019._domainkey.MAILDOMAIN.TLD. 1417 IN    TXT    "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyBjU5POfOMC0DdzxAeImIKYCWR3frj9jXD3IB7XWIYwV9CK3LP2s+gNxqffneygVPD+tvBZgHbG+kn7tQP1EtHpG0bg/KYrF09r5/f7/ilZflF9RE+t5GQkwAZCtgeZ1FWX8CEYq2kqHpGWhyhBd1l9idaqh97jk6NiuXOzrCZ9dIjoLQ2G8kAMdH7ade0/CT" "dEL4GX4Jzd8Jbb/eFXzM/2kCJ8v7lFUz5zLeMfdYvAto1U6yZ3cEYVjwpFQQZYJ77zq/eS8F/JAvJJWe5OzPnJe4V+i8hFVmsAYHpNysxUFW9KmR/LOYw8ouqpXoMMfOt3ilBLtZZO4n9Dms4iDNQIDAQAB"`

## config

Here are some relevant config files:

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD   mail

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf**

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
    -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=$mua_relay_restrictions
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender-login-maps.cf
    -o smtpd_helo_required=no
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
submission-header-cleanup unix n - n    -       0       cleanup
    -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/submission_header_cleanup
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
##
## Network settings
##

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, ::1, 10.0.42.170
myhostname = mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD


##
## Mail queue settings
##

maximal_queue_lifetime = 1h
bounce_queue_lifetime = 1h
maximal_backoff_time = 15m
minimal_backoff_time = 5m
queue_run_delay = 5m


##
## TLS settings
###

tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
tls_high_cipherlist = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA


### Outbound SMTP connections (Postfix as sender)

smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_tls_policy_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/tls-policy.cf
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt


### Inbound SMTP connections

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD/privkey.pem


##
## Local mail delivery to Dovecot via LMTP
##

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp


##
## Spam filter and DKIM signatures via Rspamd
##

smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:11332
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:11332
milter_protocol = 6
milter_mail_macros =  i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
milter_default_action = accept



##
## Server Restrictions for clients, cecipients and relaying
## (concerning S2S-connections. Mailclient-connections are configured in submission-section in master.cf)
##

### Conditions in which Postfix works as a relay. (for mail user clients)
smtpd_relay_restrictions =      reject_non_fqdn_recipient
                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain
                                permit_mynetworks
                                reject_unauth_destination


### Conditions in which Postfix accepts e-mails as recipient (additional to relay conditions)
### check_recipient_access checks if an account is "sendonly"
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/recipient-access.cf


### Restrictions for all sending foreign servers ("SMTP clients")
smtpd_client_restrictions =     permit_mynetworks
                                check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/without_ptr
                                reject_unknown_client_hostname


### Foreign mail servers must present a valid "HELO"
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =   permit_mynetworks
                            reject_invalid_helo_hostname
                            reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
                            reject_unknown_helo_hostname

# Block clients, which start sending too early
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining


##
## Restrictions for MUAs (Mail user agents)
##

mua_relay_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mua_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_sender_login_mismatch,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mua_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject


##
## Postscreen Filter
##

### Postscreen Whitelist / Blocklist
postscreen_access_list =        permit_mynetworks
                                cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop


# Drop connections if other server is sending too quickly
postscreen_greet_action = drop


### DNS blocklists
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =    ix.dnsbl.manitu.net*2
                            zen.spamhaus.org*2
postscreen_dnsbl_action = drop


##
## MySQL queries
##

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/accounts.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/domains.cf
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps


##
## Miscellaneous
##

### Maximum mailbox size (0=unlimited - is already limited by Dovecot quota)
mailbox_size_limit = 0

### Maximum size of inbound e-mails (50 MB)
message_size_limit = 52428800

### Do not notify system users on new e-mail
biff = no

### Users always have to provide full e-mail addresses
append_dot_mydomain = no

### Delimiter for "Address Tagging"
recipient_delimiter = +
```

Please help me, guys.
Cheers, Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

The solution is quite easy and I found the answer in the FAQ of the German version of that post: https://thomas-leister.de/mailserver-debian-stretch/#wieso-port-587-und-143-mit-starttls . Unfortunately, this FAQ item isn't contained in the English version of the documentation.

When connecting with the server, postfix behaves differently whether you connect to it on port :25 or on port :587. On port :587 (the submission port), the client has been authenticated - on :25 is has not.

So I had to open another port from the host to the guest, so that Thunderbird could connect with the STARTTLS submission port.